# How to auto highlight sidebar based on the current contents by user scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think I've done searching online but still unable to find a related/relevant answer online
below is the code link I've used

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GAJ71QEBNC8Q

Comment: I would advise including a transcript of the code in your post. The first URL is broken, it has a whitespace in it. Please consider the guidelines to asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We don't know what your specific problem is

Comment: sorry all, just got update in the description

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you can install Bootstrap on your website, then [use a component called scrollspy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/scrollspy/#item-1-2). It will work if everything is installed correctly.

Comment: Hi Denis, thanks for reply but actually I'm doing a html insert a website under wix so I cannot install anything; the only way is do it inside html only

Comment: @WillyLi So you do need JavaScript. However, if you cannot install jQuery, good luck and happy scripting, because that could be a lot of work. Otherwise, I do have a jQuery sample of something similar that you could potentially modify.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot; I will try to happy script then